# Does fortification buff ammo powers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Since fortification is under combat powers, if I pick power synergy which gives 20% power damage, will it buff ammo powers like incendiary or disruptor?

Comment: I never noticed an effect on ammo powers, but it seems possible.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just recently saw that with James' Incendiary Ammo, for instance, selecting the Fortification "Power Synergy" upgrade increased the damage associated with his incendiary ammo - so long as fortification was active of course.

Answer (score 1):

It does! You can easily verify this by checking your ammo power in the Group Menu with and without fortification activated. 
E.G. Incendiary ammo Rank 1 is 10% Dmg
Activate Fortification Rank 5 Choice 2
Check back to the Group Menu. Incendiary Ammo is 13% DMG

But understand: Buff percentages doesn't sum up. 30% and 40% (eg from Combat Mastery) aren't 70% more damage! You may calculate from the so called increased basic value. In simple terms: 
Ammo 10% DMG x 40% Buff Combat Mastery = 14% DMG x 30% Buff Fortification = 18% DMG

Nonetheless. If you choose all Ammo Dmg Upgrades and the Ammo Uprgrade in CM, you reach 45% DMG with IA. Activate Fortification and you should have 59%.
But alas! There are only 54%. Can't explain this, But 9% more Dmg is better then nomore DMG. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, because the ammo powers are classed / refered to (on the Mass Effect wiki) as just that - Ammo Powers. However this is something Ill gladly try and test at some point.

This is something thats worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know it doesn't buff any passive effects you get from equipment. It only improves most damage values from "spells" (i.e. biotic damage and tech damage).